# GP Modeling differs from GP result. GPO not applying

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I have a new GP "The Fix" linked to the top level of my domain. It applies a Logon script as a User Policy.

Further down I have user and computer OUs with Loopback Merge on the computer OU.

"The Fix" policy shows as being applied when looked at with the Modeling Wizard but doesn't show up as anything in the results wizard, not even as a denied GPO. I have double and triple checked domain replication, and verified the behavior on multiple computers in the same OU.

The policy does get applied on another machine that is in an OU Without Loopback processing.

I would think that loopback merge means that it would get applied but it doesn't, why is this?

If I move "The Fix" policies into another user policy at the same level that *is* working, it all works as expected. Or if I add a random Admin Template setting it works as expected... wat?

Answer (score 0):

Please erase you thefix GPO and redo it. It seem corrupt as it act like you have computer setting inside of it.

Can I ask why the loopback? as you seem to only want to apply a user GPO to all users, its a burden the loopback and more used to target like a terminal server.

Comment: Some users log into both their own laptops as well as specialized citrix servers so loopback is needed for the different user policies between those two. We've never had a problem with the loopback and processing times are really small. I actually have deleted it and recreated it twice to no avail. Any idea on how to diagnose exactly how it's corrupt?